# How to point domain to folder in FTP (not root)?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

Is this managed through the htaccess file?

- one domain + webspace at provider 1.
- one domain at provider 2.

how to point the domain from provider 2 to a subfolder from the FTP of webspace from provider 1?

I think the question is simple but it seems like I can not find the correct sentences to ask google...

Comment: You certainly don't want to use a FTP server as a file backend for the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of a http server.

Comment: You could setup the host at provider 2 as a forward proxy to a host at provider 1, but that is not exactly efficient. The question is: why do you want to make such a strange setup? Why not simply modify the DNS resolution such that provider 1 serves _both_ hosts in an efficient manner?

Comment: This questions smells a bit of a xy problem... Maybe it does make sense if you don't try to find an answer to something you hope that might solve your issue, but that you ask how you can solve your actual issue best...